# Como fazer a somatória de uma coluna de um arquivo e visualizar com .plot(kind = 'bar')?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Estou tentando fazer a somatória da coluna duration ,e apresentar utilizando `plot()`

```
trip_data['duration'].value_counts().plot(kind = 'bar')
trip_data['duration'].count_data().plot(kind = 'bar')
trip_data['duration'].size().plot(kind = 'bar')
```

mas tudo que eu tento apresenta separadamente ou dá erro, como posso fazer isso?

grato pela ajuda.
[image: Eu queria fazer a somatória da 'duration' e apresentar em um gráfico]

Comment: Olá, Claudio. Você poderia postar as primeiras linhas do DataFrame? Assim, nós poderemos ter uma ideia de como são os dados.

Answer (score 1):

Bom, você ainda não tentou tudo.

Sua apresentacão está um pouco ruim, mas se adivinhei certo o que vc está usando, deve ajudar.

Inicialmente o que você mostra é uma tabela que não tem muita coisa pra somar ou você pode somar qualquer coisa. Como também não está especificado o `type` da sua tabela, segue um exemplo de uma das maneiras de usar a funcão `bar` na `matplotlib.pyplot`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure(figsize=(17,9))
a=np.array(range(10))
b=np.cumsum(a)
plt.bar(a,b)
plt.show()
```

Tendo como resposta:
[image: Fig_1]

Caso você queira deixar o gráfico um pouco mais interessante, você pode ver [esta outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/237341/88991).