# Gráfico em Escala logarítmica com Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, matplotlib

Inicialmente criei um gráfico de Valores X tempo (tempo em Unix Time) com o seguinte código:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as dates
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

x = []
y = []
with open("dataset.csv") as f:
    for l in f:
        X,Y = l.split(",") #separador eh a virgula
        x.append(float(X))
        y.append( float (Y))

#x1 = [datetime.fromtimestamp(int(d)) for d in x]
x1 = [str(datetime.fromtimestamp(int(d)))[-8:] for d in x]
y_pos = [idx for idx, i in enumerate(y)]

plt.figure(figsize=(17,9))
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(dates.DateFormatter('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S'))

plt.bar(y_pos, y, align='edge', color="blue", alpha=0.5, width=0.5) # <--- EDICAO PRINCIPAL
plt.title("ValoresX TEMPO")
plt.ylabel("Valores")
plt.xlabel('Tempo')
plt.xticks(y_pos, x1, size='small',rotation=35, ha="right")
plt.yticks(y)
plt.ylim(ymax=sorted(y)[-1]+1) # valor maximo do eixo y
#plt.ylim(ymin=sorted(y)[0]-1) # valor minimo do eixo y

plt.show()
```

Cujo gráfico gerado é:

[image: Valores Sobrepostos]

Podem-se ver valores sobrepostos. A ideia é usar uma escala logarítimca para melhorar o gráfico, desta forma, poderemos comparar melhor os valores.
Para isso usei: `plt.yscale('log')` Assim:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as dates
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import numpy as np 

x = []
y = []
with open("dataset.csv") as f:
    for l in f:
        X,Y = l.split(",") #separador eh a virgula
        x.append(float(X))
        y.append( float (Y))


#x1 = [datetime.fromtimestamp(int(d)) for d in x]
x1 = [str(datetime.fromtimestamp(int(d)))[-8:] for d in x]
y_pos = [idx for idx, i in enumerate(y)]

plt.figure(figsize=(17,9))
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(dates.DateFormatter('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S'))

plt.bar(y_pos, y, align='edge', color="blue", alpha=0.5, width=0.5) # <--- EDICAO PRINCIPAL
plt.title("Valores X Tempo")
plt.ylabel("Valores")
plt.xlabel('Tempo')
plt.xticks(y_pos, x1, size='small',rotation=35, ha="right")
#plt.yticks(y)
#plt.yticks(np.arange(0,max(y),0.3))
plt.yticks(np.arange(0,max(y)+5,10))
plt.ylim(ymax=sorted(y)[-1]+1) # valor maximo do eixo y
#plt.ylim(ymin=sorted(y)[0]-1) # valor minimo do eixo y
plt.yscale('log')
plt.show()
```

O novo gráfico ficou assim:

[image: Escala logarítmica]

E ficou horrível.  Alguma ideia de como fazer um gráfico melhor em escala logarítmica no eixo y, mas exibindo no gráfico os valores originais?
O dataset é:

```
1491828000,3
1491828060,195
1491828120,220
1491828180,240  
1491828240,230  
1491828300,238
1491828360,310
1491828420,280
1491828480,263
1491828540,271
1491828600,282
1491828660,302
1491828720,298
1491828780,257
1491828840,245
1491828900,200
1491828960,170
1491829020,138
1491829080,59
1491829140,39
1491829200,48
1491829260,95
1491829320,151
1491829380,155
1491829440,175
1491829500,93
1491829560,25
1491829620,3
1491829680,185
1491829740,233
1491829800,210
1491829860,86
1491829920,32
1491829980,46
1491830040,51
1491830100,201
1491830160,129
1491830220,116
1491830280,105
1491830340,200
1491830400,203
```

Alguma ideia de como fazer um gráfico melhor em escala logarítmica no eixo y, mas exibindo no gráfico os valores originais?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema é a ordem de chamada.

Chame `plt.yscale('log')` e depois chame `plt.ylim(ymax=sorted(y)[-1]+100,ymin=sorted(y)[0]-1)`.

Veja que adicionei 100 ao valor máximo, devido a escala logarítima. Caso você queira a barra bem justa ao topo, você pode usar um valor menor. Para ficar com um bom espaçamento entre o topo das barras e o limite do gráfico, similar a escala linear, é necessário um valor grande, pra ser mais específico [uma ordem de grandeza](https://pt.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escala_logar%C3%ADtmica) maior.

Também notei que conforme a chamada do `yticks`, você pode ter problemas similares. Mas ele parece sempre chamar os valores automáticos, que ficaram com uma ótima apresentacão. Lembre-se que você deve avisar o leitor do gráfico que esta escala é logarítima e a melhor maneira de fazer isso é com os *ticks colocados de acordo*. `matplotlib.ticker` tem uma funcão específica para ajustar os ticks na escala log, caso os valores originais não estejam ao seu gosto.
Caso você queira muito colocar os `ticks` com os valores originais -- *que ficam sobrepostos e não passam bem a idéia do logaritmo* -- tem algumas [perguntas no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45671786/how-to-change-log-scale-tick-labels-in-matplotlib) original [que fazem isso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14530113/set-ticks-with-logarithmic-scale). O codigo abaixo quando colocado depois da declaracão dos limites mencionada acima faz o trabalho:

```
import matplotlib.ticker # vai para as primeiras linhas

ymajorLocator = matplotlib.ticker.FixedLocator(locs=y) 
ymajorFormatter = matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter()
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_locator( ymajorLocator )
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter( ymajorFormatter )
plt.gca().minorticks_off()
```

Veja que tirei todos os `minorticks` por ser o mais rápido. Existem solucão melhores nas respostas mencionadas acima, porém elas requerem um bom tempo pra ver exatamente o que fica melhor: um gráfico decente toma tempo.

Alias, vc pode dar uma [incrementada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/237341/88991) no seu gráfico :P .

Edit 1 e 2: Explicação da escala log & ticks, respectivamente.

Comment: Não entendi porquê adicionou 100. Poderia explicar?

Comment: nao tem como aparecerem os valores reais no eixo Y? A ideia era só mudar a escala mas manter os valores originais...   Estão aparecendo apenas potências de 10

Comment: Gostaria de exbir os valores originais no eixo Y, tentei variações mas não consigo!

Comment: Editada. Alias, se era o que vc esperava, vc pode aceitar a resposta, assim evita de ficar uma pergunta pendente mas respondida conforme o usuario queria.